# Odd to_tsquery results for s:* and t:*

Tags: postgresql

I was experimenting with PostgreSQL's text search feature - particularly with the normalization function **to_tsquery**.

I was using **english** dictionary(config) and for some reason **s** and **t** won't normalize. I understand why **i** and **a** would not, but **s** and **t**? Interesting.

Are they matched to single space and tab?

Here is the query:

```sql
select
to_tsquery('english', 'a:*') as for_a, 
to_tsquery('english', 's:*') as for_s, 
to_tsquery('english', 't:*') as for_t, 
to_tsquery('english', 'u:*') as for_u
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/32081) just in case.

You would see **'u:*'** is returning as ***'u:*'*** and **'a:*'** is not returning anything.

Comment: They are normalised. They are just normalised into nothing

Comment: Correct! But why to nothing - there has to be a reason. A and I would normalize to nothing because article/pronoun rule for the English dictionary config, or at least that is what I think. What could be the reason for S/T?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The letters `s` and `t` are considered stop words in the english text search dictionary, therefore they get discarded. You can read the stop word list under `tsearch_data/english.stop` in the postgres shared folder, which you can locate by typing `pg_config --sharedir`
With pg 11 on ubuntu/debian/mint, that would be

`cat /usr/share/postgresql/11/tsearch_data/english.stop`

Quoting from the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-STOPWORDS),

> Stop words are words that are very common, appear in almost every document, and have no discrimination value. Therefore, they can be ignored in the context of full text searching.

It is best to discard english grammar and think of words in a programmatic and logical way as described above. Full text search does not try to infer context based on sentence structuring so it has no use for these words. After all, it's called full text search and not natural language search.

As to how they arrived on the conclusion to add `s` and `t` to the stop word list, statistical analysis must have revealed these characters to be noise.